# HTML Select cant declare Selected Option

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a Service List and i want to set the Selected option as the first Service of my list. I found this code and for other instances it works but not for this. And i dont understand why,

```
public Servicelist: Array<ServiceModel> = []

// I fill it via a webservice where i return a JSON
this.Servicelist = await this.service.GetServicelist()
```

```
<select [(ngModel)]="SelectedService">
    <option *ngFor="let s of Servicelist; let i = index"
            [value]="s.id"
            [selected]="i == 0">
        {{s.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `ngModel` variable to the first id in the list

```
this.SelectedService = this.Servicelist[0].id
```